# Can I connect a monitor with EVERY USB-C port?

Tags: usb, display, external-display, usb-c

I owned a [Microsoft Surface Go](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/p/surface/8v9dp4lnknsz?invsrc=search&cl_vend=google&cl_ch=sem&cl_camp=1581729319&cl_adg=61366419524&cl_crtv=296946851442&cl_kw=microsoft%20surface%20go&cl_pub=google.com&cl_place=&cl_dvt=c&cl_pos=1t2&cl_mt=e&cl_gtid=aud-374935196045%3Akwd-447352838837&cl_pltr=&cl_dim0=W7uEewAAAOzRnjaw%3A20181010225009%3As&OCID=AID695933_SEM_W7uEewAAAOzRnjaw%3A20181010225009%3As&s_kwcid=AL!4249!3!296946851442!e!!g!!microsoft%20surface%20go&activetab=pivot%3Aoverviewtab) which have an USB-Type-C USB port. Since now I used USB-ports just for periphals and also have a USB-graphic Adapter for an older Notebook.

There exist some cables USB-C to DP or HDMI. So can I just connect my Surface via USB to a Monitor? I don't Need an extra graphic Adapter than before? Or has it to be a special USB-C port to support Monitors?

Sorry for this newbie Question, but before I buy this (expensive) cable I just want to make sure that this will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type-C port can be a multifunctional port if it is designed so. A standard Type-C port was introduced as "USB only", and all other "alternative" uses of this connector are optional.

To some surprise, the basic MANDATORY function of a Type-C port is **USB 2.0** functionality, see section 5.1 of [USB Type-C specifications](http://www.those.ch/designtechnik/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/USB-Type-C-Specification-Release-1.0.pdf) Rev.1.3. So technically one shouldn't expect even USB 3.0 functionality over a arbitrary Type-C port, and definitely not any more sophisticated alternatives as DisplayPort or PowerDelivery.

However, per most recent USB Type-C specifications, all alternate modes require the use of a subset of PowerDelivery protocol, so-called "Structured VDMs", to mutually identify "link partner" capabilities.

There do exist Type-C to DP cables, but they won't function unless the host port supports this "alternate" functionality. If no alternate mode supported, you will still need your old USB-graphics Adapter.